# is there some problem when using the 2d map built by slam in uneven ground?

Tags: navigation, mapping, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the 2d map has't the height item.
Is there some problem when using the 2d map built by slam in uneven ground?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391258/is-there-some-problem-when-using-the-2d-map-built-by-slam-in-uneven-ground?/) by [wyfeng2013](https://answers.ros.org/users/88939/wyfeng2013/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2021-11-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are different solutions to work with uneven grounds while performing SLAM.

For example there is  ROS package from ANYbotics for elevation mapping:
https://github.com/ANYbotics/elevation_mapping

> The software is designed for (local)
> navigation tasks with robots which are
> equipped with a pose estimation (e.g.
> IMU & odometry) and a distance sensor
> (e.g. structured light (Kinect,
> RealSense), laser range sensor, stereo
> camera). The provided elevation map is
> limited around the robot and reflects
> the pose uncertainty that is
> aggregated through the motion of the
> robot (robot-centric mapping).

Another solution is to use 3D octomap to capture elevation information as well:
https://octomap.github.io/

> The OctoMap library implements a 3D
> occupancy grid mapping approach,
> providing data structures and mapping
> algorithms

You may also look at another ROS package Cartographer.

> Cartographer is a system that provides
> real-time simultaneous localization
> and mapping (SLAM) in 2D and 3D across
> multiple platforms and sensor
> configurations.

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wyfeng2013](https://answers.ros.org/users/88939/wyfeng2013/) on 2021-11-23**:
@osilva
Thanks for your very much!